# R: Efficiently remove singleton dimensions from array

Tags: arrays, r, reshape2

I am looking for a fast way to remove redundant dimensions from an array in R, similar to the `squeeze()` command in MATLAB.
Right now I combine the `melt()` and the `cast()` commands from the `reshape2` package, but there should be a less intricate way of doing the same.

This is how I do it so far:

```
    require(reshape2)
    array3d <- array(rep(0,4),dim=c(1,2,2)) # create a 2*2 matrix within a 3-d array
    acast(melt(array3d),Var2~Var3) # recover the matrix
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `drop()`, which "delete[s] the dimensions of an array which have only one level".

```
drop(array3d)
#       [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
# [2,]    0    0
```